# Lubuntu's asking password for shutting down

Tags: lubuntu, password, shutdown, restart

I've Lubuntu 13.04 64 Bit on my Lenovo Y570. System works well but Lubuntu's asking my password when I want to shutdown or restart the computer.

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in Lubuntu 13.04, I have been having the same since I upgraded. For me it happens occasionally, reporting that there are "other user(s) logged in on the system". Is that the same message that you are getting?

I suspect there's a link with a `find` cron job that is ran by user 'nobody', about daily it seems. Given that it started with 13.04, it *might* be search indexing for PCManFM's new search feature. Unfortunately, this would make it a genuine Lubuntu bug rather than an easily fixable problem - which means it should be reported in the Lubuntu bugtracker.

(Posted as answer because I couldn't find how to comment on the question)